# Octave not finding a function (streamline) in the octave package

Tags: ubuntu, octave

I'm using Octave 5.2 on Ubuntu 20.04. Copypasting the [example](https://octave.org/doc/ref/octave/function/streamline.html)

```
[x, y] = meshgrid (-1.5:0.2:2, -1:0.2:2);
u = - x / 4 - y;
v = x - y / 4;
streamline (x, y, u, v, 1.7, 1.5);
```

in a m-file and launching the script, gives

```
warning: the 'streamline' function is not yet implemented in Octave

Please read <https://www.octave.org/missing.html> to learn how you can
contribute missing functionality.
error: 'streamline' undefined near line 4 column 1
error: called from
quiverexample at line 4 column 1
```

yet I believe it should be present in the 5.2 version (streamline was implemented on the [23/11/2019](https://hg.savannah.gnu.org/hgweb/octave/log/8dd0fca2a3d9/scripts/plot/draw/streamline.m) and the 5.2 version was built on [31/01/2020](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/news.html)). Should I build Octave from source or there are other ways to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it, `streamline` was added to octave from v6 onwards: https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/NEWS-6.1.html#alphabetical-list-of-new-functions-added-in-octave-6

You can simply try downloading the relevant m-file from the dev sources. Alternatively, download the latest octave from source and compile it, it's actually a very straightforward process. (and if you run into trouble feel free to ask here)

Comment: I had to read the news more carefully, thanks!